# Network-admin for server?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, network-manager

I am running a 12.04 distro.  I am looking for something that can run in command line on my server that would give me access to change the network settings.  Similar programs would be `network-admin` or `netconf` but these require the graphical interface which I do not have on my server.  Only command line.

Any suggested packages?

Edit

I was hoping that I can change the IP address, DNS, Gateway and such and have those settings saved for reboot.  I've set a static IP with `ifconfig` before but upon reboot it seemed to go back the default network IP.  I removed the GUI to limit process and space taken up. The embedded device I am using does not have a huge storage. It is actually an ARM system distro. I went into the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and it seemed to not have any settings saved for primary network.  I was really hoping there would be an easy way to accomplish this, something like address X.X.X.X that it will take what the network address is versus a static? If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `nmcli` ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/nmcli.1.html)).

It is already installed on Ubuntu.

Example output

```
tim@Hairy14:~$ nmcli -p c
======================================================================================================================
                                                   Connection list
======================================================================================================================
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tim's Phone Network       39bdb4e5-bce2-498e-ba2f-326e9601ea21   bluetooth         never
Hotspot                   e9d19b97-a01e-4017-9f64-3f663f5a025b   802-11-wireless   Mon 28 Jul 2014 10:56:02 BST
Tim's Phone Network       e0f716d4-c84f-4cd0-8ff6-140471583bea   bluetooth         never
Wired Connection RIP      516797eb-78cf-4930-9d3a-b0be1b861f42   802-3-ethernet    Wed 23 Jul 2014 12:01:28 BST
Wired connection SIP      57816f79-049b-4ecc-806c-c48278845fc2   802-3-ethernet    Wed 30 Jul 2014 16:52:14 BST
```

Options:

```
tim@Hairy14:~$ nmcli
Usage: nmcli [OPTIONS] OBJECT { COMMAND | help }

OPTIONS
  -t[erse]                                   terse output
  -p[retty]                                  pretty output
  -m[ode] tabular|multiline                  output mode
  -f[ields] <field1,field2,...>|all|common   specify fields to output
  -e[scape] yes|no                           escape columns separators in values
  -n[ocheck]                                 do not check nmcli and NetworkManager versions
  -v[ersion]                                 show program version
  -h[elp]                                    print this help

OBJECT
  nm              NetworkManager's status
  c[onnection]    NetworkManager's connections
  d[evice]        devices managed by NetworkManager

tim@Hairy14:~$ nmcli -p
Usage: nmcli [OPTIONS] OBJECT { COMMAND | help }

OPTIONS
  -t[erse]                                   terse output
  -p[retty]                                  pretty output
  -m[ode] tabular|multiline                  output mode
  -f[ields] <field1,field2,...>|all|common   specify fields to output
  -e[scape] yes|no                           escape columns separators in values
  -n[ocheck]                                 do not check nmcli and NetworkManager versions
  -v[ersion]                                 show program version
  -h[elp]                                    print this help

OBJECT
  nm              NetworkManager's status
  c[onnection]    NetworkManager's connections
  d[evice]        devices managed by NetworkManager
```

So to display the status of nm:

```
nmcli -p nm
```

Comment: Just being curious, can you configure existing interfaces and add new connections? It seems focused on getting information instead of setting it.

Comment: @Cijco Don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

While not a command line solution, you can always install [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) and administer the server remotely. I've used it often and it is really easy without much to a learning curve. You can install it from [Here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/12/install-webmin-official-repository-ubuntu/). - Although the nmcli suggestion is a good one, I just wanted to point out another option.

Comment: If you use Webmin in a production environment, please [secure](http://serverfault.com/questions/139430/how-do-i-make-webmin-secure) [it](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=999600) and keep yourself informed about [security vulnerabilities](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-358/Webmin.html) and [official announcements](http://www.webmin.com/security.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the, /etc/network/interfaces, file with the IP settings that you want.
example

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Your file should look something like this

```
## dh2 generated for "machine name" : 2014-07-09 15:37:35

# gateway address space is 'xxx'

# xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# assigned : "machine name" : machine : 
iface eth0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    up route add -net x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x gw x.x.x.x dev eth0 || true
    down route delete -net x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x gw x.x.x.x dev eth0 || true
    up route add -net x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x gw x.x.x.x dev eth0 || true
    down route delete -net x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x gw x.x.x.x dev eth0 || true

# loopback
iface lo inet loopback

# auto interfaces (all of them!)
auto eth0 lo
```

Comment: Yes, I am currently attempting to try and write a script to prompt the user to write the IP address they need.  Hopefully all works out well.